# Designing an API: Use the Data Layer objects or copy/duplicate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

Struggling with this one today.

Rewriting a web-based application; I would like to do this in such a way that:

- All transactions go through a web services API (something like **http://api.myapplication.com**) so that customers can work with their data the same way that we do / everything they can do through our provided web interface they can also do programmatically
- A class library serves as a data layer (SQL + Entity Framework), for a couple of design reasons not related to this question

Problem is, if I choose not to expose the Entity Framework objects through the web service, **it's a lot of work to re-create "API" versions of the Entity Framework objects and then write all the "proxy" code to copy properties back and forth**.

What's the best practice here? Suck it up and create an API model class for each object, or just use the Entity Framework versions?

Any shortcuts here from those of you who have been down this road and dealt with versioning / backwards compatibility, other headaches?

**Edit:** After feedback, what makes more sense may be:

- **Data/Service Layer** - DLL used by public web interface directly as well as the Web Services API
- **Web Services API** - almost an exact replica of the Service Layer methods / objects, with API-specific objects and proxy code

Comment: BTW, the idea behind "we use our own web services" is so that we, too, would feel the pain if making a decision that would impact customer applications... good idea?

Comment: It's good to use same Service Layer for your own application's as you provide to customers, but you should use it directly (call Service methods directly) without WCF transport.

Comment: just to expound a bit: WCF adds a tremendous amount of additional "wrapping" around each request.  By forcing your website to constantly create this wrapping and send it across the wire can radically increase your internal network traffic and, therefore, artificially reduce the availability of your machines.  It makes no sense and is generally frowned on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would NOT have the website post data through the web services interface for the API.  That way leads to potential performance issues of your main website.  Never mind that as soon as you deploy a breaking API change you have to redeploy the main website at the same time.  There are reasons why you wouldn't want to be forced to do this.

Instead, your website AND web services should both communicate directly to the underlying business/data layer(s).

Next, don't expose the EF objects themselves.  The web service interface should be cleaner than this.  In other words it should try and simplify the act of working with your backend as much as possible.  Will this require a fair amount of effort on your part? yes.  However, it will pay dividends when you have to change the model slightly without impacting currently connected clients.

Comment: quote "Instead, your website AND web services should both communicate directly to the underlying business/data layer(s)." I think he wanted to say that he uses the same Service Layer (not data layer), and I think he doesn't use WCF for it internally, he just calls same Service methods natively.

Comment: isn't the "problem" here that if we discover performance problems, then we have to make better web services? Trying to prevent devs from pushing the web services aside in favor of more efficient internal methods that customers can't use..

Comment: @routeNpingme: No. In your case, the web server would have to make one or more outbound web service calls for each page request that comes in.  At minimum, this doubles the amount of network connections the server has to make (realisticly a 5 to 10x increase) while offering nothing in return.  The web site should directly talk to the business/data layer, the web services should also directly talk to those.  Any performance issues should be in the business/data layer and therefore easily fixed for both "views"

Comment: makes sense, didn't think about that much of a performance degradation, edited question to reflect a design change - excellent point.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on project complexity and how long you expect it to live. For small, short living projects you can share domain objects across all layer's. But if it's big project, and you expect it to exist, work well, and update for next 5 years....

In my current project (which is big), I first started with shared entities across all layers, then i discovered that I need separate entities for Presentation, and now (6 month's passed) I'm using separate classes for each layer (persistence, service, domain, presentation) and that's not because i'm paranoid or was following some rules, just I couldn't make all work with single set of classes across layers... Make you conclusions..

P.S. There are tools that can help you convert your objects, like Automapper and Value Injecter.

Answer (score 0):

I would just buck up and create an API specifically aimed at the needs of the application. It doesn't make much sense to what amounts to exposing the whole DB layer. Just expose what needs to be exposed in order to make the app work, and nothing else.